# What is the command that replaces 'drush variable-set'?

Tags: drush, 8

In Drupal 8 the Drush command `drush variable-set` no longer works.

From reading ([here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1667896)) it appears that Drupal 8 has a new "configuration" system that replaces the old (Drupal <=7) "variables". But what is the new Drush command to achieve the same ends?

Specifically I want to convert the commands:

```
drush variable-set site_mail someone@email.com
drush variable-set update_notify_emails someone@email.com
```

to the new Drupal8/Drush8 equivalent...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Following some more research it seems the new command is:

- `drush config-set <config-name> <key>` (where the old format was `drush variable-set <name> <value>`). Alias: `cset`.

So I'm not totally sure that I have this right (so comment and/or another answer from someone who does would be great...), but it seems that the config that includes emails are: `contact.form.feedback recipients`, `update.settings notification.emails` and `system.site mail`.

This update is the result for some good discussion (below).
Note that some settings are arrays (rather than strings):

```
www/drupal8# drush config-get update.settings notification
'update.settings:notification':
  emails:
    - admin@example.com
  threshold: all
```

to update this you need to run:

```
drush -y config-set update.settings notification.emails.0 admin2@example.com
```

Source: [Leverage Drush 7 for Drupal 8](https://www.acquia.com/blog/leverage-drush-7-drupal-8).

<sup>Note: Drush 7 no longer supports Drupal 8, but this still applies.</sup>

Comment: There's also drush cedit, that allows you to edit the file in an editor. I guess you'd need notification.emails.0 or so to set it to a list, not sure.

Comment: The changed format may cause your notifications to fail. In the original case `email` is an array containing `admin@example.com` (i.e. multiple email addresses), but in your result you've turned `email` into a string containing `admin2@example.com` (i.e. single email address).

Comment: @Alma - Thanks for the heads up. How do I make sure that it get's entered as an array?

Comment: @Berdir - Is that what you meant when you said notification.emails.0?

Comment: Yes. Berdir's solution works. So you'd do "drush config-set update.settings notification.emails.0 admin@example.com". Just tested it myself now.

Comment: A `drush config-list` will print every possible category of configuration for you to parse through. In case you are ever in need of finding them all.

Answer (score 6):

Additional follow-up,

To find the identifiers for the config to get or set,

- You can NO LONGER guess at the machine names of variables just by inspecting system settings forms. There used to be a 1:1:1 match between the form element seen on many config screens, the `$config['varname']` you could put into `$settings.php`, and drush vset/vget
- The config manager in the ui (found at `admin/config/development/configuration/single` ) provides something of a variable browser.

I wanted to update my `local.settings.php` to always disable css & js aggregation when downsyncing.

D7 :

```
$conf['preprocess_css'] = FALSE;
$conf['preprocess_js'] = FALSE;
```

D8 :

```
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = 0;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = 0;
```

(And note that this type of override WILL NOT show up in your Admin UI, or in `drush config-get` ...  though it will take effect)

Comment: Drush command for disabling aggregation then is:
`drush -y config-set system.performance css.preprocess 0` && `drush -y config-set system.performance js.preprocess 0`

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. It's a Drush PHP EVAL command.

```
drush ev '\Drupal::state()->set("MY_VARIABLE", "MY_VALUE")'
```

Here it's being used to set the state of MY_VARIABLE

You can also *get* the state of a variable:

```
drush ev 'echo \Drupal::state()->get("MY_VARIABLE")'
```